# Как сделать появление блока со смещением его соседей?

Tags: javascript, css

Вот так это должно выглядеть (чтобы посмотреть нажмите на плей сверху справа), именно с анимацией а не мгновенное появление.

https://www.figma.com/file/cBmVenHRn3Tm9nYN3TB7O0/question?node-id=0%3A1

Я сделал это через отрицательные margin, но есть ли способ покрасивее? Блоки могут быть любой высоты, поэтому задание фиксированной высоты не подходит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать `max-height:0`

```
{
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 0.15s ease-out;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

А при появлении:

```
{
    max-height: 500px;
    transition: max-height 0.25s ease-in;
}
```

Только установить какое то значение большое, которое блок никогда не достигнет

Comment: фиксированная высота блока не подходит т.к. в разных блоках разное количество контента

Comment: Это не фиксированная высота, а максимальная. Поставь её в 10000px, главное что бы временные функции были правильно выставленны иначе будет медленно исчезать или появляться

Comment: а почему блоки появляются быстрее чем исчезают даже с одинаковым transition?

Comment: Потому что расчет идет на всю высоту max-height. Для этого и задается transition-timing-function, что бы при появлении сначала анимация шла медленно, а потом быстро, а при скрытии наоборот

Comment: https://cubic-bezier.com/ - сдесь можно сгенерировать свои временные функции под свою конкретную задачу. P.S. Про 10000px это я образно сказал, надеюсь Вы не поставили такую высоту

Comment: т.е. чем больше максимальная высота тем дольше будет длиться анимация появления?

Comment: Нет, вы задаете высоту и время, а transition за указанное время увеличивает элемент на указанную высоту. Увеличивается только на необходимую высоту, но расчет происходит для всей возможной высоты. Поэтому и задаются временные функции, которые контролируют с какой скоростью выполнять увеличение на определенных участках

Answer (score 0):

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.anim__container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  color: white;
}

.anim__item__content {
  padding: 10px;
}

.anim__item:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-color: #ED6565;
}

.anim__item:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #CAED65 0%, #65EDB4 100%);
  max-height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: 40s animateHeight ease-in-out forwards;
}

.anim__item:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: #ED9E65;
}

@keyframes animateHeight {
  0% {
    max-height: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    max-height: 100000px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="anim__container">
  <div class="anim__item">
    <div class="anim__item__content">
      123
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="anim__item">
    <div class="anim__item__content">
      123
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="anim__item">
    <div class="anim__item__content">
      123
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```